# Container ADT standard operation

Tags: data-structures, stack, abstract-data-type

If you look at the Container ADT (abstract data type) as a black box, it provides two functions:

```
1. put(C, x)
2. get(C)
```

The first function will put the object x into container C. The second will retrieve the "next" object from container C, where "next" depends on what type of container you want. A stack implementation would return the element that was most recently put into the container (also known as a FILO ADT).

My question is, in it's most generic form, does the Container ADT function get() remove the element itself from the container, or does it simply return a reference to it for access, retaining the element in the Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have only `put()` and `get()`, `get()` must also remove the element, otherwise you won't have access to the nth element for each n!=1.

the idea is with enough `get()` oporations, you should be able to access each element in the container, and if `get()` doesn't remove the element, sequential `get()`'s will always return the same element, so only the first element is accessable.

but it can be different for each implementation, of course. (for example, you can create a ADT with put(), get() and pop(), where get will only return the element.